# Clone specific repository branch with GitHub CLI

Tags: github, github-actions, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a specific branch (the "dev" branch) of a GitHub repository. With the git command I can run something like

```
git clone --branch dev https://github.com/user/repo
```

What's the equivalent of this in `gh` (GitHub CLI)? I can't find it in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
git clone link_repo -b branch_name --single-branch
```

In your case, we use cmd:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo -b dev --single-branch
```

Comment: @HritikSharma thank you both for your answers, I've found the same on the internet few time ago. I think the answer to my question is "you can't do that with `gh`", while I thought that  `gh` was just a more powerful version of `git`! Now I know I was wrong, but I still don't know the purpose of `gh`, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the git parameters to the gh command:

```
gh repo clone <repository> [<directory>] [-- <gitflags>...]
```

E.g:

```
gh repo clone <repo> -- -b <branch> --single-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command to clone a specific `branch`.

```
git clone --single-branch --branch <branch-name> <url>
```

Example:

```
git clone --single-branch --branch dev https://github.com/test-repo.git
```

where, `dev` is the `branch` name.

`https://github.com/test-repo.git` is the url.